# Sony Vaio - Black Screen on Debian Install

Tags: boot, laptop, debian, sony-vaio, display-driver

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-C2S laptop. It currently has Windows 7 installed on it, but I would like to install Debian. I downloaded the Debian 8 CD 1 image, burned it onto a CD, installed a new, blank hard drive in my computer (I need to keep my Windows documents / files for the moment and do not want to dual boot), and tried to boot from the CD.

The laptop does boot off the CD, as the initial ISOLINUX message is displayed briefly before the computer switches to a blank display. At this point the Debian installer menu has loaded but is not being displayed. This can be seen because if the return key is pressed, the CD spins up as if it is going to begin the installation. Whatever key is pressed at the blank screen, no graphics are displayed, now at the main menu, or later in the installation process.

I tried using the same install CD in a similar laptop (Sony Vaio VGN-C1Z) and it loaded the Debian installer menu perfectly.

The computer that does not work has a Core 2 CPU and 3GB of RAM.

Does anyone know what is going wrong, and how to fix it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you still need the answer as it is more than one year since your post, but anyway, for others benefit.

The problem is caused by BIOS setting (my guess is that source of the problem is VAIO logo) and nvidia driver bug in Debian distribution.

To avoid the black screen follow these steps:

1. Boot from CD/DVD and wait until ISOLINUX message is displayed.
2. Pres Esc key several times. It will bring you boot prompt.
3. You can type *help* to see all posaible options, or just type *install vga=normal*. The installation will start.
4. Finish the installation.

The laptop will restart after the installation and show again the black screen. You have to set kernel boot option *nomodeset* in /etc/default/grub. This step may be done even during the installation (instead of *vga=normal*), but I did not try it